# C++ build error in Netbeans using MinGW and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, makefile, mingw

I have installed the MinGW compiler and I am attempting to run a C++ QT Application from within Netbeans.

As you can see from this screenshot, I have successfully set up the native build tools using Netbeans:

[image]

Unfortunately when attempting to run my program, I get the following error:

```
make.exe": /bin/sh: Command not found
make.exe": /bin/sh: Command not found
make.exe": *** [.validate-impl] Error 127

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 303ms)
```

Just to be clear, I am not running a complicated program, in fact, I am just trying to execute a basic generated main file:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

You can download my Makefile-Debug and Makefile-impl here: http://wikisend.com/download/467700/makefiles.zip

I would be extremely grateful for your help.

Comment: I don't believe you have set up your tools correctly. This: `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`, among a bunch of MinGW native windows tools, in a non-MSYS container application. suggests that you are attempting to invoke the MSYS `make` command _without_ a properly initialized MSYS shell process container. Such usage is definitively _unsupported_ by the MSYS developers, so it may not be too surprising if it doesn't work.

Comment: Please verify your MSYS works well.

Comment: Well, not a quite solution but I had been trying to run wxWidgets, MinGW with Eclipse. This was a quite similar problem of yours. I tried too many times. But they were never as good as developing under Linux. If I were you, I would develop Qt applications for Linux and after compile them for Windows. I'd use Arch Linux for cross-compilation system. Because there are newest versions of commonly used libraries (wx, qt, boost, ..) in AURs. Trust me, after a while this will be the best solution. Development under Windows, is a torture unless you use Visual Studio. :(

Comment: It's a big headache. I am trying to learn C++ and it's taking me the last week just trying to get to the blooming stage anything can run. Visual Studio it is. I'll just have to compile separately for other platforms. Thanks again for your help. Not off to a good start.